# Is there any way to generate n number of lines with array values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, tuples

I am having json files and iterating through the each json object

My JSON file :

```
{
 "User" :{"name":["Eagle","Humming Bird"]}
}
```

Pythn code:

```
 for j in json.object:
     print j
 print j
```

whenever i am runing my python ,output was "Humming Bird"Last object only

I need to get all the objects
My expected output :

```
  Bird : Eagle
  Bird : Humming Bird
```

if json file has 2 object ,then it generate 2 statement above like this

Comment: Please update your question with your read code. Include reading from your file and converting from the json format. Also, why should the output lines start with `"Bird"`?

Comment: What version of Python is this?

Comment: @quamrana : if i have 8 birds,i need to generate single output that has  8 bird name has my expected output..."Bird " for ,my study purpose i am doing this

Comment: So, you still haven't posted your real code, but it looks like the answer from Yehdhih ANNA should work for you.

Comment: That will work.It willl print 8 times if i have 8 object in json @quamrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json object, you have one key : "User" whose value is another json/dict , and you are trying to acess the list of birds which is the value of the key : "name" in the inner object.

So basicly you just need to specify that in your code and here's how :

```py
import json
x = '{"User" : {"name":["Eagle","Humming Bird"]} }'
y = json.loads(x)
for bird in y["User"]["name"] :
    print("Bird : ",bird)
```

Comment: it will print as i expect and what here is when you print "bird" outside,it will print last object only...I need to print all as my expected output...I created a list and append element as well.that didnt work as i expected